# JSF preRenderView called too many times

Tags: java, jsf-2, facelets

A page/bean of mine has its `preRenderView` event fired twice on the first page load then `2 + n` times for each postback, where `n` is the number of postbacks (including the current one) that have occurred.

After reading a few other posts here, I moved `<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="myBean.preRenderView"/>` outside of `<f:metadata/>` and that reduced the number of `preRenderView` calls by one. That is, it is called once on the full page load and `1 + n` times for each postback. I even tried to move the `<f:event/>` tag outside of `<f:view/>`, but it had no effect.

I'm not sure if this is relevant: The page uses a template:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <ui:insert name="metadata"/>
        <h:head>
            <!-- Some stuff here -->
            <ui:insert name="content"/>
            <!-- More stuff here -->
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

And the relevant bits of the page:

```xml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title></title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/myLayout.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="windowTitle">My Page</ui:define>
            <ui:define name="metadata">
                <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myBean.preRenderView}"/>
            </ui:define>
            <ui:define name="content">
                <!-- Some content here -->
                <h:panelGroup id="reRenderable" layout="block">
                    <!-- More content here -->
                    <h:form prependId="false">
                        <h:outputLabel for="mySelector" value="Item:"/>
                        <h:selectOneMenu id="mySelector"
                                         value="#{myBean.item}"
                                         converter="#{myConverter}"
                                         validator="#{itemActiveValidator.validate}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.myItems}"/>
                            <f:ajax render=":reRenderable"/>
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                    </h:form>
                    <!-- More content here -->
                </h:panelGroup>
                <!-- More content here -->
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like yet another Mojarra bug: [JAVASERVERFACES-2162](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2162)

I applied the workaround as follows and it works:

```xml
<ui:define name="metadata">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="dummy"/>
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myRecordsBean.preRenderView}"/>
    </f:metadata>
</ui:define>
```

All that's left to do is push `dummy` up to the template to keep the pages that use it free from this filth.

Comment: That's a nasty bug :( If you, or anyone else, are bothered by this, please vote for the bug.

Comment: Already did. I'm coming across glaringly obvious Mojarra bugs with increasing frequency lately. It's not like I'm trying to shoehorn exotic designs and weird use cases into the framework.

Comment: You're right, although to be honest I'm encountering glaringly obvious bugs in just about every piece of software I use (Hibernate, Firefox, you name it) :(

Comment: @SteveTaylor what do you mean "push dummy up to the template"?

Comment: I mean move `<f:viewParam name="dummy"/>` from each page that defines it into the template that each page uses. Having said that, I'm not sure if it would actually work, but that is of no concern to me now that the bug is fixed.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
@ManagedBean
@XScoped --sessionScope,viewScope   
Public class MyRecordsBean{
public void preRenderView(){
 if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback(){
 //put initView codes here
}
```

}

Comment: I think you didn't understood the concrete problem.

Comment: @BalusC is right. This problem occurs with postbacks therefore your postback check will pass for every duplicate event. You answer solves *a* problem, just not this one. -1

Comment: Ok. You are right. I miss read 2 + n times for each postback part.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. I don' t know tecnical differences between your code and mine below. I changed  `<ui:insert name="content"/>` 
location to between body tags from head tags. And add `f:metadata`.
 But when I use like this this does not call twice. **Works fine.** it can be about page structure. Maybe about using html tag twice. You need one. But complete pages missing parts, only missing parts with composition blocks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
         xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
         xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
         xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

    <f:view contentType="text/html">
         <f:metadata>
             <ui:insert name="metadata"/>
          </f:metadata>


        <h:body>
              <!-- Some stuff here -->
              <ui:insert name="content"/>
              <!-- More stuff here -->
        </h:body>
     </f:view>
    </html>




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="/WEB-INF/templates/myLayout.xhtml">




        <ui:define name="windowTitle">My Page</ui:define>
        <ui:define name="metadata">
            <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myBean.preRenderView}"/>
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="content">
            <!-- Some content here -->
            <h:panelGroup id="reRenderable" layout="block">
                <!-- More content here -->
                <h:form prependId="false">
                    <h:outputLabel for="mySelector" value="Item:"/>
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="mySelector"
                                     value="#{myBean.item}"
                                     converter="#{myConverter}"
                                     validator="#{itemActiveValidator.validate}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.myItems}"/>
                        <f:ajax render=":reRenderable"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </h:form>
                <!-- More content here -->
            </h:panelGroup>
            <!-- More content here -->
        </ui:define>
   </ui:composition>
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with including the html tag in both the template and the page that uses it. Everything outside `<ui:composition/>` is ignored.

Comment: Things I said about ui:comp is may be about issue. But real change I made in code if you look carefully. I put your '<ui:insert name="metadata"/>' in f:metadata tag and moved your content from head to body. It works perfect in may case. I thing it is about f:metadata. Can you try? İf this does not work I don' t write anything promise :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't put `<f:metadata/>` in the template. The spec states as much and I can tell you from first-hand experience (as part of researching the answer to this question) it just doesn't work in Mojarra. Otherwise I'd definitely do that and put the workaround (`dummy` view parameter) in the template.